# maximum length of an HTTP message?

Tags: http

In a conditionally compliant/general-purpose server, something likes this

```
#define HTTP_MSG_LEN_MAX = ??;

...

int read_request(sockfd, ...)
{
  char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * http_msg_len_max + 1);
  int read_total = 0;
  int read_once = 0;

    while (zStrFind(buf, "\r\n\r\n") != -1 && read_total < HTTP_MSG_LEN_MAX) {
      read_once = read(sockfd, buf + read_total, HTTP_MSG_LEN_MAX - read_total);

     if (read_once < 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "read failed: %s \n", strerror(errno));
       free(buf);
       return -1;
     }

     read_total += read_once;
  }

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

I already know [maximum length of HTTP URI in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request),
but what's the maximum length of an HTTP message?
[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) doesn't mentions it.

Comment: imo you can/should use a buffer and realloc it if it's too small while you process the reads

Comment: I'm think developer could define this limit by himself, and it should be larger than 8192 bytes.

Finally, I'm define it in compiling option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximum length (per specification).